# Insert data into existing table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I create a student table and I try to insert data into that student table using a stored procedure.

Help me to insert data using stored procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    student_id   integer not null ,
    student_name varchar(100),
    student_age  integer,
    mobile_no    varchar(20)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_student
    (@student_id   int,
     @student_name varchar(100),
     @student_age  varchar(100),
     @mobile_no    varchar(20)) 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO students (student_id, student_name, student_age, mobile_no)
    VALUES (@student_id, @student_name, @student_age, @mobile_no);
END;
```

Comment: What is your question? Please add more information about what isn't working and what you've tried so far.

Comment: What is the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are on LUW. Remove the `AS` in your `CREATE PROCEDURE ...` statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_student(
                            @student_id   int,
                            @student_name varchar(100),
                            @student_age  varchar(100),
                            @mobile_no    varchar(20)
                            )
BEGIN
...
```

See [CREATE PROCEDURE (SQL) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-procedure-sql)